# Yii2 cant sort in calculated values

Tags: sorting, yii2

In my model i have

```
public function getRating(){
        $rating=ShopRating::getRating($this->id);
        if($rating)
            return $rating->rating;
        else
            return 0;
}
```

And in search model i have created a virtual column like

```
public $rating;
```

and marked it as safe

```
[['rating'], 'safe']
```

And in the controller defined my sort

```
private function getSort(){
        $sort = new Sort([
        'attributes' => [
            'date-asc' => [
                'asc' => ['date' => SORT_ASC],
                'label' => Inflector::camel2words('Old to New'),
            ],
            'date-desc' => [
                'desc' => ['date' => SORT_DESC],
                'label' => Inflector::camel2words('New to Old'),
                'default' => SORT_DESC,
            ],
            'rating-desc' => [
                'desc' => ['rating' => SORT_DESC],
                'default' => SORT_DESC,
            ],
            'rating-desc' => [
                'desc' => ['rating' => SORT_DESC],
                'default' => SORT_DESC,
            ],
            ],
        ]);
        return $sort;
}
```

like this.

```
$sort=$this->getSort();
```

And my date-wise sort is working perfectly.But the sorting on the calculated value doesn't work. Meaning sorting with the rating asc and desc is not working. How to can I make it to work

Comment: yii directly sort form database | query

Comment: you can use ArrayDataProvider for short data  https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider